# What is difference between CrudRepository and JpaRepository interfaces in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

What is the difference between [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) and [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) interfaces in [Spring Data JPA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa)?

When I see the examples on the web, I see them there used kind of interchangeably.

1. What is the difference between them?
2. Why would you want to use one over the other?

Comment: Also read this article's section [Introduction to Spring Data Repositories](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-introduction/)

Answer (score 1499, accepted):

[`JpaRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) extends [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) which in turn extends [`CrudRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html).

Their main functions are:

- [`CrudRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) mainly provides CRUD functions.
- [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html) provides methods to do pagination and sorting records.
- [`JpaRepository`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) provides some JPA-related methods such as flushing the persistence context and deleting records in a batch.

Because of the inheritance mentioned above,  `JpaRepository` will have all the functions of `CrudRepository` and `PagingAndSortingRepository`. So if you don't need the repository to have the functions provided by `JpaRepository` and `PagingAndSortingRepository` , use `CrudRepository`.

Comment: and returns a List<> instead of Iterable<> in findAll() :-)

Answer (score 512):

Ken's answer is basically right but I'd like to chime in on the "why would you want to use one over the other?" part of your question.

### Basics

The base interface you choose for your repository has two main purposes. First, you allow the Spring Data repository infrastructure to find your interface and trigger the proxy creation so that you inject instances of the interface into clients. The second purpose is to pull in as much functionality as needed into the interface without having to declare extra methods.

### The common interfaces

The Spring Data core library ships with two base interfaces that expose a dedicated set of functionalities:

- `CrudRepository` - CRUD methods
- `PagingAndSortingRepository` - methods for pagination and sorting (extends `CrudRepository`)

### Store-specific interfaces

The individual store modules (e.g. for JPA or MongoDB) expose store-specific extensions of these base interfaces to allow access to store-specific functionality like flushing or dedicated batching that take some store specifics into account. An example for this is `deleteInBatch(…)` of `JpaRepository` which is different from `delete(…)` as it uses a query to delete the given entities which is more performant but comes with the side effect of not triggering the JPA-defined cascades (as the spec defines it).

We generally recommend *not* to use these base interfaces as they expose the underlying persistence technology to the clients and thus tighten the coupling between them and the repository. Plus, you get a bit away from the original definition of a repository which is basically "a collection of entities". So if you can, stay with `PagingAndSortingRepository`.

### Custom repository base interfaces

The downside of directly depending on one of the provided base interfaces is two-fold. Both of them might be considered as theoretical but I think they're important to be aware of:

1. **Depending on a Spring Data repository interface couples your repository interface to the library.** I don't think this is a particular issue as you'll probably use abstractions like `Page` or `Pageable` in your code anyway. Spring Data is not any different from any other general purpose library like commons-lang or Guava. As long as it provides reasonable benefit, it's just fine.
2. **By extending e.g. `CrudRepository`, you expose a complete set of persistence method at once.** This is probably fine in most circumstances as well but you might run into situations where you'd like to gain more fine-grained control over the methods expose, e.g. to create a `ReadOnlyRepository` that doesn't include the `save(…)` and `delete(…)` methods of `CrudRepository`.

The solution to both of these downsides is to craft your own base repository interface or even a set of them. In a lot of applications I have seen something like this:

```
interface ApplicationRepository<T> extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Long> { }

interface ReadOnlyRepository<T> extends Repository<T, Long> {

  // Al finder methods go here
}
```

The first repository interface is some general purpose base interface that actually only fixes point 1 but also ties the ID type to be `Long` for consistency. The second interface usually has all the `find…(…)` methods copied from `CrudRepository` and `PagingAndSortingRepository` but does not expose the manipulating ones. Read more on that approach in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.definition-tuning).

### Summary - tl;dr

The repository abstraction allows you to pick the base repository totally driven by you architectural and functional needs. Use the ones provided out of the box if they suit, craft your own repository base interfaces if necessary. Stay away from the store specific repository interfaces unless unavoidable.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it is not only more complete but also more authoritative because it was written by the "Spring Data Project Lead".  Thank you!

Comment: I am curious as to why saveAndFlush is a method that is only part of something like the JpaRepository? Isn't flushing the persistence context a generic operation? How would we go about having the same functionality without using a technology specific interface - per your recommendation?

Comment: @Oliver Drotbohm Sorry for the very late question, you say "they expose the underlying persistence technology" but I thought that JPA was just a specification, not an implementation? For example I use Hibernate, but I try to avoid Hibernate-specific code, and I thought using JPA classes instead was better, but maybe there is something I didn't understand?

Answer (score 125):

[image]

**Summary:**

- PagingAndSortingRepository extends CrudRepository
- JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository

The **CrudRepository** interface provides methods for CRUD operations, so it allows you to create, read, update and delete records without having to define your own methods.

The **PagingAndSortingRepository** provides additional methods to retrieve entities using pagination and sorting.

Finally the **JpaRepository** add some more functionality that is specific to JPA.

Comment: What about "extends Repository<>"? Which methods will it have? Same as CrudRepository?

Answer (score 33):

I am learning Spring Data JPA. It might help you:
[image]

Comment: Hi, nice scheme. Which tool do you use to generate this kind of scheme please?

Comment: @RozarFabien u asked few years back and I hope u found out how, but i put it here for reference for others too. In the picture of this quesiton I am not sure which tool but, you cna easily do it using Intellij (or any of their IDEs really, depending on the language u use) here their docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html#analyze_class

Answer (score 30):

Below are the differences between [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) and [`JpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) as:

## `CrudRepository`

1. `CrudRepository` is a base interface and extends the [`Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html) interface.
2. `CrudRepository` mainly provides CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations.
3. Return type of `saveAll()` method is [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html).
4. Use Case - To perform CRUD operations, define repository extending `CrudRepository`.

## `JpaRepository`

1. `JpaRepository` extends [`PagingAndSortingRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html?is-external=true) that extends `CrudRepository`.
2. `JpaRepository` provides CRUD and pagination operations, along with additional methods like `flush()`, `saveAndFlush()`, and `deleteInBatch()`, etc.
3. Return type of `saveAll()` method is a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).
4. Use Case - To perform CRUD as well as batch operations, define repository extends `JpaRepository`.

Answer (score 19):

### Recent update, **`spring-data-jpa 3.x`**

As of **`spring-data-jpa 3.x`** used with **`spring-boot 3.x`** and **`spring-core 6.x`**,

the structure and the hierarchy has been modified and seems to be more clear.

`ListCrudRepository` extends `CrudRepository`

`ListPagingAndSortingRepository` extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`

`JpaRepository` extends both `ListCrudRepository`, `ListPagingAndSortingRepository`.

So basically the new introduced interfaces of `ListPagingAndSortingRepository`, `ListCrudRepository` now represent the functionalities of the old interfaces but with returned types of **`List<T>`** while the remaining `PagingAndSortingRepository`, `CrudRepository` handle the return types of **`Iterable<T>`**

In the new (3.x) version the structure is the following:

[image]

In the past (before 3.0) many of the declared methods which returned **`List<T>`** have been directly declared inside the `JpaRepository`, but now with separate interfaces for those methods they have been extracted into `ListPagingAndSortingRepository`, `ListCrudRepository`.

So the structure before (3.x) was

[image]

I hope it is clear from the above schemas how the mentioned `JpaRepository` and `CrudRepository` have been modified in `3.x` version.

In case you plan to **migrate `spring-data-jpa`** from `2.x` into `3.x` (would be necessary if you migrate from **`spring-boot 2.x`** to **`spring-boot 3.x`**)  as illustrated in the above schemas you should expect to have breaking code in cases where you have used the `PagingAndSortingRepository` in your code, as in the past it was extending from `CrudRepository` and so your custom repository which extended directly the `PagingAndSortingRepository` already had access to the methods of `CrudRepository`. If this is the issue you should fix this by adapting your custom repository to also extend either the `ListCrudRepository` or the `CrudRepository`.

Answer (score 11):

> What is the difference between CrudRepository and JpaRepository
> interfaces in Spring Data JPA?

Spring Data JPA provides both `JpaRepository` and `CrudRepository` interfaces to simplify the creation of repositories for data access in JPA-based applications.

`CrudRepository` is the base interface for entities with basic CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) operations. `CrudRepository` provides a minimal set of methods like `save()`, `findAll()`, `findById()`, `delete()`, etc., and can be extended by other custom methods.

It is the code example:

```
public interface PersonEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {

}
```

`JpaRepository` interface extends `CrudRepository` interface.
`JpaRepository` interface provides other additional methods to the basic CRUD operations provided by CrudRepository such as:

- `findAll(Sort sort)` - a method which returns all entities sorted by the given criteria.
- `findAll(Pageable pageable)` - a method which returns a Page of entities according to the given pagination and sorting criteria.
- `flush()`  - a method which flushes all pending changes to the database.
- `saveAndFlush(T entity)` - a method which saves an entity and immediately flushes changes to the database.
  It is the code example:

```
public interface PersonEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {

    List<TestEntity> findByName(String name);

    List<Employee> findByAgeGreaterThan(double age);
}
```

> Why would you want to use one over the other?

Choosing between the two depends on the specific needs of your application. I would recommend to use `CrudRepository` interface for basic CRUD operations, and `JpaRepository` interface for more advanced functionality such as pagination, sorting, and immediate flushing of changes to the database.

Answer (score 10):

All the answers provide sufficient details to the question. However, let me add something more.

**Why are we using these Interfaces:**

- They allow Spring to find your repository interfaces and create proxy objects for them.
- It provides you with methods that allow you to perform some common operations (you can also define your custom method as well). I love this feature because creating a method (and defining query and prepared statements and then execute the query with connection object) to do a simple operation really sucks !

**Which interface does what:**

- **CrudRepository**: provides CRUD functions
- **PagingAndSortingRepository**: provides methods to do pagination and sort records
- **JpaRepository**: provides JPA related methods such as flushing the persistence context and delete records in a batch

**When to use which interface:**

According to http://jtuts.com/2014/08/26/difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-in-spring-data-jpa/

Generally the best idea is to use **CrudRepository** or **PagingAndSortingRepository** depending on whether you need sorting and paging or not.

The **JpaRepository** should be avoided if possible, because it ties you repositories to the JPA persistence technology, and in most cases you probably wouldn’t even use the extra methods provided by it.

Answer (score 2):

Crud Repository is the base interface and it acts as a marker interface.

JPA repository also extends the PagingAndSorting repository.
It provides all the method for which are useful for implementing pagination. Crud Repository doesn't provide methods for implementing pagination and sorting

You can refer - [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-in-java#:~:text=Crud%20Repository%20is%20the%20base,acts%20as%20a%20marker%20interface.&text=JPA%20repository%20also%20extends%20the,for%20implementing%20pagination%20and%20sorting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-in-java#:%7E:text=Crud%20Repository%20is%20the%20base,acts%20as%20a%20marker%20interface.&text=JPA%20repository%20also%20extends%20the,for%20implementing%20pagination%20and%20sorting).

Comment: `CrudRepository` is not a marker interface. https://www.baeldung.com/java-marker-interfaces#:~:text=A%20marker%20interface%20is%20an,also%20called%20a%20tagging%20interface. Also there are very few (possibly 0) instance of checks for it in the code, so it doesn't act as one either.