# Are you supposed to have one repository per table in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Are you supposed to have one repository per table in JPA? If not, how do you resolve the generics in the repository database?

For example, below is a `StoreRepository`. It handles *CRUD* operations on the `Store` object. If I wanted the repository to save a `StoreEvent` object as well, how would I go about changing the interface below to accommodate both objects?

```
@Repository
public interface StoreRepository extends JpaRepository<Store, String> {
    public Store findByGuid(String guid);
}
```

Comment: Almost duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538775/is-there-a-mismatch-between-domain-driven-design-repositories-and-spring-data-on

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As repository is a concept derived from [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_driven_design), thinking about database tables is the wrong approach. By definition you access aggregate roots from a repository. Effectively a repository is simulating a collection of these.

Now what forms an aggregate root? Probably even more interesting: what does not? That's, of course, highly dependent on your domain, but let me give you an example here. An `Order` containing `LineItems` usually is modeled as an aggregate root. This is due to the composition nature of the `Order`. A `LineItem` would not exist without a surrounding `Order`.

Usually the persistence access mechanisms should follow the domain principles. Thus, you'd model both `Order` and `LineItem` as `@Entity` classes but only create an `OrderRepository`, as they form the aggregate root and effectively control the consistency rules within the object graph.

We also *strongly* recommend *not* to use the store specific repository base interfaces as they - as the name suggests - expose store specifics (e.g. `flush()`) to the clients of which they shouldn't be aware, if possible. Read more on that in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784007/18122).

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you suggest that LineItem should be modeled as `@Entity` if it does not have a life cycle that is independent of its parent entity Order. I believe it should be modeled as `@Embeddable` in its defining class LineItem and not as `@Entity`.

Comment: You could have a `LineItemRepository`. You could save a new`LineItem` before adding it to an `Order`. Is this a bad practice? If it is, then why?