# Hibernate does not delete parent entity in OneToMany to composite key, instead of deleting key and entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have 2 main entities: `Client` and `Bundle`. They have a bidirectional ManyToMany relationship which works as expected. Examples:

1. A client has several bundles. I delete the client. All the bundle entities are updated with that client removed, but the bundles entities remain.
2. I update a client and remove a bundle from its `Set<Bundle>`. That same bundle will have its `Set<Client>` updated with the client removed. The bundle entity will remain.

All of this works both ways.

Both `Client` and `Bundle` have a OneToMany relationship, as composite key, with an entity `ClientBundleApproval`. which also has an an enum (APPROVED, REJECTED, PENDING).

**My problem is:** Assuming I have several entities configured. A client has several bundles, and several approvals pending. When I'm trying to delete a client, **it will not be deleted** if there exists a row with composite key that includes it in `ClientBundleApproval`.

My expected outcome was, that all rows in `ClientBundleApproval` containing that client's ID would be deleted, and all bundles would have their collection of related approvals removed, and clients updated (basically a cascade delete, but only to the composite key table and not to the other entity). Adding a cascade delete causes deleting a client to delete the composite key, but also the bundle (which is not the wanted behavior).

I need help figuring out if my configuration is the problem, or is it just not possible. I assume that maybe I should remove the composite key rows first, but I am required to keep the logic of the services handling those entities separate. (for example, in a `ClientService` to not have to inject other entities' `JpaRepository<T, ID>`)

**Implementation notes:** I am using Spring JPA, so for every entity I have an interface extending Spring's `JpaRepository<T, ID>`, which I inject to service classes and do CRUD operations with instead of an `EntityManager`.

I have tried removing the mappedBy from the OneToMany, different types of cascade (both in the relationship declaration and using `@Cascade`), with and without orphan removal. Nothing I could think of worked.

Entities and a diagram:

*Client* (I removed some boilerplate)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_details")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @JoinTable(
            name = "client_bundle",
            joinColumns =  { @JoinColumn(name = "client_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "bundleName") }
    )
    @Column(name = "bundles")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER /* all types of cascade except delete */)
    private Set<Bundle> clientBundles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true /* all types of cascade except delete */)
    private List<ClientBundleApproval> approvals;

}
```

*Bundle*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bundle")
public class Bundle implements Serializable {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="clientBundles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER /* all types of cascade except delete */)
    private Set<Client> clients;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bundle", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true /* all types of cascade except delete */)
    private List<ClientBundleApproval> approvals;

}
```

*ClientBundleApproval*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_bundle_approval")
public class ClientBundleApproval implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClientBundleKey clientBundleKey;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER /* all types of cascade except delete */)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @MapsId("clientId")
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER /* all types of cascade except delete */)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bundle", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @MapsId("bundleId")
    private Bundle bundle;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ClientBundleApprovalStatus approvalStatus;

}
```

*ClientBundleKey*

```
@Embeddable
public class ClientBundleKey implements Serializable{
    private String clientId;
    private String bundleId;
}
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277087/66686

Comment: @JensSchauder I'm not sure that I can understand how that answer helps me. Both of my entities `Client` and `Bundle` are completely independent of each other (a bundle can have no clients and vice versa). Regarding `ClientBundleApproval`, what I understand from that answer is that I'm not supposed to have a `JpaRepository` for it, and I should manage this table by updating the client. Is that correct ? And even then, I am still facing the same problem. And the last paragraph states not to expose those `JpaRepository` directly to clients. I do not do that, I use them in dedicated services

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It's not intended to fix your current problem. But you mention: "I am using Spring JPA, so for every entity I have an interface extending Spring's JpaRepository<T, ID>" which is a common antipattern discussed in the answer I linked to.

Comment: @maydawn hi! I've met the same problem. Do you remember how you had fixed it?