# Which Spring Data repository to choose when you use an INNER JOIN or return attributes from several entities?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, inner-join, spring-repositories

Working with Spring Data JPA repositories and with the methods annotated with `@Query` like the below one, I dont know if this query should be in the `UserRepository` or `AddressRepository` in this case. Its even more complicated when you want to return attributes from both entities. Thanks!

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u.name from User u JOIN u.address a where u.emailAddress = :emailAddress  and a.zipcode=:zipcode")
  User findByEmailAddressAndZipCode(String emailAddress, String zipcode);
}
```

Comment: I would create a `Repository` that acts like an middle tier between both of them, maybe call it `UserAddressRepo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns a `User` I'd therefore expect it to exist in the `UserRepository`.
The `User` already knows about `Address` via the attribute of the same name, so it is ok for the `UserRepository` to do so as well.

The fact that the `User` contains a reference to the `Address` is otherwise irrelevant for picking the **right** repository.

If you have queries returning something completely different from `User` and `Address`, e.g. some statistics about the number of users per city, it could make sense to have a separate repository, either based on an entity mapped to a view or a complete custom implementation independent of Spring Data. That kind of entity and repository live in a different [Bounded Context](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BoundedContext.html).

Another question you should consider though is if you need/want a `AddressRepository` at all. We obviously hardly know your domain, but from what I see it seems likely that an `Address` does not exist independent from a `User` and therefore should be part of the `User`-Aggregate and not have its own repository.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21277087/66686

Comment: Ok, understood, I was thinking in the  example above but a little modified like the next one   @Query("select a.zipCode from User u JOIN u.address a where u.emailAddress = :emailAddress ")
  String findZipCodeByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);