# What are differences between delete(Iterable<? extends T> itrbl) in CrudRepository and deleteInBatch(Iterable<T> itrbl) in JpaRepository

Tags: spring, hibernate, primefaces

I'm getting an issues when trying to delete a list of entities which have a foreign key. A delete method in `CrudRepository` work fine with table doesn't have foreign key but when I tried to delete a list of entities have foreign key, it reported success but nothing was delete in database. The `deleteInBatch()` work fine in both.

What is differences between the method `delete(Iterable<? extends T> itrbl)` in `CrudRepository and deleteInBatch(Iterable<T> itrbl)` in `JpaRepository`?

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring).

Any help would be appreciated

My model SmsNotifyTemplate.java:

```
package com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Anh Nguyen
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "SMS_NOTIFY_TEMPLATE", catalog = "", schema = "VPCRF")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "SmsNotifyTemplate.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM SmsNotifyTemplate s"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SmsNotifyTemplate.findBySmsNotifyTemplateId", query = "SELECT s FROM SmsNotifyTemplate s WHERE s.smsNotifyTemplateId = :smsNotifyTemplateId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SmsNotifyTemplate.findByMessageTemplate", query = "SELECT s FROM SmsNotifyTemplate s WHERE s.messageTemplate = :messageTemplate"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SmsNotifyTemplate.findByComments", query = "SELECT s FROM SmsNotifyTemplate s WHERE s.comments = :comments"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "SmsNotifyTemplate.findBySmsTemplateCode", query = "SELECT s FROM SmsNotifyTemplate s WHERE s.smsTemplateCode = :smsTemplateCode")})
public class SmsNotifyTemplate implements Serializable {

    public static enum COLUMNS {

        COMMENTS, LANGID, MESSAGETEMPLATE, SMSNOTIFYTEMPLATEID, SMSTEMPLATECODE
    };
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "SMS_NOTIFY_TEMPLATE_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sms_notify_template_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sms_notify_template_seq_gen", sequenceName = "SMS_NOTIFY_TEMPLATE_SEQ")
    private Short smsNotifyTemplateId;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE_TEMPLATE", length = 480)
    private String messageTemplate;
    @Column(name = "COMMENTS", length = 200)
    private String comments;
    @Column(name = "SMS_TEMPLATE_CODE")
    private Integer smsTemplateCode;
    @JoinColumn(name = "LANG_ID", referencedColumnName = "LANG_ID", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Lang langId;

    public SmsNotifyTemplate() {

    }

    public SmsNotifyTemplate(Short smsNotifyTemplateId) {
        this.smsNotifyTemplateId = smsNotifyTemplateId;
    }

    public Short getSmsNotifyTemplateId() {
        return smsNotifyTemplateId;
    }

    public void setSmsNotifyTemplateId(Short smsNotifyTemplateId) {
        this.smsNotifyTemplateId = smsNotifyTemplateId;
    }

    public String getMessageTemplate() {
        return messageTemplate;
    }

    public void setMessageTemplate(String messageTemplate) {
        this.messageTemplate = messageTemplate;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public Integer getSmsTemplateCode() {
        return smsTemplateCode;
    }

    public void setSmsTemplateCode(Integer smsTemplateCode) {
        this.smsTemplateCode = smsTemplateCode;
    }

    public Lang getLangId() {
        return langId;
    }

    public void setLangId(Lang langId) {
        this.langId = langId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (smsNotifyTemplateId != null ? smsNotifyTemplateId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof SmsNotifyTemplate)) {
            return false;
        }
        SmsNotifyTemplate other = (SmsNotifyTemplate) object;
        return !((this.smsNotifyTemplateId == null && other.smsNotifyTemplateId != null) || (this.smsNotifyTemplateId != null && !this.smsNotifyTemplateId.equals(other.smsNotifyTemplateId)));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.viettel.pcrf.model.SmsNotifyTemplate[ smsNotifyTemplateId=" + smsNotifyTemplateId + " ]";
    }

}
```

I have a mapper to map the model with a normal class:

SmsTemplateMapper.java:

```
package com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.mapper;

import com.viettel.fw.common.util.mapper.BaseMapper;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.dto.SmsTemplateDTO;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.model.SmsNotifyTemplate;

public class SmsTemplateMapper extends BaseMapper<SmsNotifyTemplate, SmsTemplateDTO> {

    @Override
    public SmsTemplateDTO toDtoBean(SmsNotifyTemplate model) {
        SmsTemplateDTO obj = null;
        if (model != null) {
            obj = new SmsTemplateDTO();
            obj.setComments(model.getComments());
            obj.setMessageTemplate(model.getMessageTemplate());
            obj.setSmsNotifyTemplateId(model.getSmsNotifyTemplateId());
            obj.setSmsTemplateCode(model.getSmsTemplateCode());
            obj.setLangId(model.getLangId());
        }
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public SmsNotifyTemplate toPersistenceBean(SmsTemplateDTO dtoBean) {
        SmsNotifyTemplate obj = null;
        if (dtoBean != null) {
            obj = new SmsNotifyTemplate();
            obj.setComments(dtoBean.getComments());
            obj.setMessageTemplate(dtoBean.getMessageTemplate());
            obj.setSmsNotifyTemplateId(dtoBean.getSmsNotifyTemplateId());
            obj.setSmsTemplateCode(dtoBean.getSmsTemplateCode());
            obj.setLangId(dtoBean.getLangId());
            System.out.println(obj.getLangId().getNationality());
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

SmsTemplateDTO.java:

```
package com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.dto;

import com.viettel.fw.dto.BaseDTO;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.model.Lang;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SmsTemplateDTO extends BaseDTO implements Serializable {

    public String getKeySet() {
        return keySet;
    }
    private String comments;
    private String messageTemplate;
    private Short smsNotifyTemplateId;
    private Integer smsTemplateCode;
    private Lang langId;

    public String getComments() {
        return this.comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public String getMessageTemplate() {
        return this.messageTemplate;
    }

    public void setMessageTemplate(String messageTemplate) {
        this.messageTemplate = messageTemplate;
    }

    public Short getSmsNotifyTemplateId() {
        return this.smsNotifyTemplateId;
    }

    public void setSmsNotifyTemplateId(Short smsNotifyTemplateId) {
        this.smsNotifyTemplateId = smsNotifyTemplateId;
    }

    public Integer getSmsTemplateCode() {
        return this.smsTemplateCode;
    }

    public void setSmsTemplateCode(Integer smsTemplateCode) {
        this.smsTemplateCode = smsTemplateCode;
    }

    public Lang getLangId() {
        return langId;
    }

    public void setLangId(Lang langId) {
        this.langId = langId;
    }

}
```

SmsTemplateRepo.java:

```
package com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.repo;
import com.viettel.fw.persistence.BaseRepository;
import java.util.List;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.model.SmsNotifyTemplate;

public interface SmsTemplateRepo extends BaseRepository<SmsNotifyTemplate>, SmsTemplateRepoCustom {


    public List<SmsNotifyTemplate> findByComments(String comments);

    public List<SmsNotifyTemplate> findByMessageTemplate(String messageTemplate);

    public List<SmsNotifyTemplate> findBySmsNotifyTemplateId(Short smsNotifyTemplateId);

    public List<SmsNotifyTemplate> findBySmsTemplateCode(Integer smsTemplateCode);
}
```

BaseRepository extends JpaRepository.

A delete method will be in deleteSmsNotifyTemplates method in this class:

SmsTemplateServiceImpl.java:

```
package com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.service;

import com.viettel.fw.common.util.extjs.FilterRequest;
import com.viettel.fw.dto.BaseMessage;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.repo.SmsTemplateRepo;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.mapper.SmsTemplateMapper;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.dto.SmsTemplateDTO;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.model.SmsNotifyTemplate;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 *
 * @author Anh Nguyen
 */
@Service
public class SmsTemplateServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl implements SmsTemplateService {

    private final SmsTemplateMapper mapper = new SmsTemplateMapper();

    @Autowired
    private SmsTemplateRepo repository;
    public Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SmsTemplateService.class);

    @Override
    public BaseMessage deleteSmsNotifyTemplates(List<SmsTemplateDTO> smsNotifyTemplateDTOs) throws Exception {
        BaseMessage baseMessage = new BaseMessage();
        repository.delete(mapper.toPersistenceBean(smsNotifyTemplateDTOs));
        baseMessage.setSuccess(true);
        baseMessage.setOutputObject(smsNotifyTemplateDTOs);
        return baseMessage;
    }         
}
```

The Controller:

SmsTemplateCtrl.java:

```
package com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.controller;

import com.viettel.fw.Exception.LogicException;
import com.viettel.fw.common.util.extjs.FilterRequest;
import com.viettel.fw.web.controller.BaseController;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.dto.LangDTO;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.dto.SmsTemplateDTO;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.model.Lang;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.service.LangService;
import com.viettel.pcrf.webconfig.service.SmsTemplateService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 *
 * @author Anh Nguyen
 */
@Component("smsNotifyTemplateController")
@Scope("view")
public class SmsTemplateCtrl extends BaseController implements Serializable {

    private List<SmsTemplateDTO> listSmsNotifyTemplate;
    private SmsTemplateDTO smsNotifyTemplate;
    private List<SmsTemplateDTO> selectedSmsNotifyTemplates;
    private List<LangDTO> listLang;

    @Autowired
    private SmsTemplateService smsNotifyTemplateService;

    @Autowired
    private LangService langService;

    public List<SmsTemplateDTO> getListSmsNotifyTemplate() {
        return listSmsNotifyTemplate;
    }

    public void setListSmsNotifyTemplate(List<SmsTemplateDTO> listSmsNotifyTemplate) {
        this.listSmsNotifyTemplate = listSmsNotifyTemplate;
    }

    public SmsTemplateDTO getSmsNotifyTemplate() {
        return smsNotifyTemplate;
    }

    public void setSmsNotifyTemplate(SmsTemplateDTO smsNotifyTemplate) {
        this.smsNotifyTemplate = smsNotifyTemplate;
    }

    public List<SmsTemplateDTO> getSelectedSmsNotifyTemplates() {
        return selectedSmsNotifyTemplates;
    }

    public void setSelectedSmsNotifyTemplates(List<SmsTemplateDTO> selectedSmsNotifyTemplates) {
        this.selectedSmsNotifyTemplates = selectedSmsNotifyTemplates;
    }

    public List<LangDTO> getListLang() {
        return listLang;
    }

    public void setListLang(List<LangDTO> listLang) {
        this.listLang = listLang;
    }

    /**
     * Khoi Tao Cac doi tuong de load len view
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        listSmsNotifyTemplate = smsNotifyTemplateService.findAllSort();
        listLang = langService.findAllSort();
        formStatus = getFormStatus();
    }

    /**
     * Chuan bi cho thao tac delete
     */
    public void delete() {
        try {
            if (selectedSmsNotifyTemplates == null || selectedSmsNotifyTemplates.isEmpty()) {
                reportError("msgInfo", "Choose one row!");
            } else {
                smsNotifyTemplateService.deleteSmsNotifyTemplates(selectedSmsNotifyTemplates);
                reportSuccess("msgInfo", "common.msg.success.delete");
                reset();
                updateController();
            }
        } catch (LogicException logicE) {
            reportError("msgInfo", logicE);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            reportError("msgInfo", exception.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Kiem tra SmsNotifyTemplateId ton tai trong bang SMS_NOTIFY_TEMPLATE
     *
     * @param smsNotifyTemplates
     * @return
     */
    public boolean SmsNotifyTemplateIdExistedInSmsNotifyTemplate(List<SmsTemplateDTO> smsNotifyTemplates) {
        List<FilterRequest> listReq = new ArrayList<>();
        for (SmsTemplateDTO s : smsNotifyTemplates) {
            listReq.add(new FilterRequest("LANGID", s.getLangId()));
        }
        List<SmsTemplateDTO> list = smsNotifyTemplateService.findAll(listReq);
        return !list.isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Kiem tra SmsNotifyTemplateCode ton tai trong bang LANG
     *
     * @param smsTemplateCode
     * @param smsNotifyTemplateId
     * @return
     */
    public boolean SmsTemplateCodeExisted(Integer smsTemplateCode, Short smsNotifyTemplateId) {
        List<FilterRequest> listReq = new ArrayList<>();
        listReq.add(new FilterRequest("SMSTEMPLATECODE", smsTemplateCode));
        List<SmsTemplateDTO> list = smsNotifyTemplateService.findAll(listReq);
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (list.size() > 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return !list.get(0).getSmsNotifyTemplateId().equals(smsNotifyTemplateId);
        }
    }

}
```

And the xhtml page. I'm using primefaces framework.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:composition template="../../templates/layoutTemplate.xhtml" >
        <ui:define name="title">SMS Notify Template Configuration</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="featureName">SMS Notify Template Configuration</ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="frmSmsNotifyTemplate">
                <p:dataTable var="tabSmsNotifyTemplate"
                             id="smsNotifyTemplateList"
                             value="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.listSmsNotifyTemplate}"
                             selection="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.selectedSmsNotifyTemplates}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,50"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             paginator="true"
                             rows="10"
                             paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                             sortMode="single"
                             sortBy="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.smsNotifyTemplateId}"
                             rowKey="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.smsNotifyTemplateId}" >
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
                    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@([id$=btnEdit]) @([id$=btnDelete])" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@([id$=btnEdit]) @([id$=btnDelete])" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="@([id$=btnEdit]) @([id$=btnDelete])" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="@([id$=btnEdit]) @([id$=btnDelete])" />
                    <p:column headerText="ID" style="width: 100px;">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.smsNotifyTemplateId}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Message Template" style="width: 100px;" sortBy="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.messageTemplate}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.messageTemplate}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="SMS Template Code" sortBy="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.smsTemplateCode}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.smsTemplateCode}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Language" sortBy="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.langId.nationality}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.langId.nationality}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Comments" sortBy="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.comments}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{tabSmsNotifyTemplate.comments}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <div align="left">
                            <span class="vt-button">
                                <p:commandLink
                                    action="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.prepareInsert()}"
                                    process="smsNotifyTemplateList"
                                    update="@form"
                                    resetValues="true"
                                    style="margin-right:30px;border: none">
                                    <p:graphicImage style="width:10px;height:10px;"
                                                    value="/resources/themes/images/icon-add.png"/>
                                    <span class="vt-button-text">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{lang['common.button.add']}"/>
                                    </span>
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.formStatus}"
                                        value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_ADD}"/>
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink
                                    id="btnEdit"
                                    action="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.prepareEdit()}"
                                    process="smsNotifyTemplateList"
                                    update="@form"
                                    disabled="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.selectedSmsNotifyTemplates.size()&gt;1 or smsNotifyTemplateController.selectedSmsNotifyTemplates==null or smsNotifyTemplateController.selectedSmsNotifyTemplates.size()==0}"
                                    resetValues="true"
                                    style="margin-right:30px;border: none">
                                    <p:graphicImage style="width:10px;height:10px;"
                                                    value="/resources/themes/images/icon-edit.png"/>
                                    <span class="vt-button-text">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{lang['common.button.edit']}"/>
                                    </span>
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                        target="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.formStatus}"
                                        value="#{vpcrfConst.BTN_EDIT}"/>
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink
                                    id="btnDelete"
                                    action="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.delete()}"
                                    immediate="true"
                                    update="@form"
                                    disabled="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.selectedSmsNotifyTemplates.size()==0 or smsNotifyTemplateController.selectedSmsNotifyTemplates==null}"
                                    resetValues="true"
                                    style="margin-right:30px;border: none">
                                    <p:graphicImage style="width:10px;height:10px;"
                                                    value="/resources/themes/images/icon-delete.png"/>
                                    <span class="vt-button-text">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{lang['common.button.delete']}"/>
                                    </span>
                                    <p:confirm header="Delete" message="Are you sure? (Ok/Cancel)" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:growl id="testMsg" showSummary="false" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" sticky="true" />
                <p:focus context="editPanel"/>
                <p:fieldset legend="SMS Notify Template Detail" rendered="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.smsNotifyTemplate!=null}">
                    <h:panelGrid id="editPanel"
                                 columnClasses="vocs-120, vocs-300"
                                 columns="2" rendered="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.smsNotifyTemplate!=null}">
                        <p:outputLabel for="smsID" value="ID" />
                        <p:inputText id="smsID"
                                     value="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.smsNotifyTemplate.smsNotifyTemplateId}"
                                     required="true"
                                     maxlength="15"
                                     disabled="true"
                                     style="min-width: 300px;"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="messTemplate" value="Message Template" />
                        <p:inputText id="messTemplate"
                                     value="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.smsNotifyTemplate.messageTemplate}"
                                     required="true"
                                     maxlength="60"
                                     style="min-width: 300px;"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="langId" value="SMS Notify Template" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="langId" 
                                         required="true"
                                         value="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.smsNotifyTemplate.langId.langId}"
                                         style="width: 306px;">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Language"
                                          itemDisabled="true" 
                                          noSelectionOption="true"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.listLang}"
                                           var="l"
                                           itemLabelEscaped="true"
                                           itemValue="#{l.langId}" 
                                           itemLabel="#{l.nationality}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:outputLabel for="templateCode" value="Template Code" />
                        <p:inputTextarea id="templateCode"
                                         value="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.smsNotifyTemplate.smsTemplateCode}"
                                         required="true"
                                         maxlength="10"
                                         style="min-width: 300px;"/>
                        <p:outputLabel for="comments" value="Comments" />
                        <p:inputTextarea id="comments"
                                         value="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.smsNotifyTemplate.comments}"
                                         required="false"
                                         maxlength="10"
                                         style="min-width: 300px;"/>
                        <div />
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <p:commandButton
                                value="OK"
                                process="editPanel"
                                rendered="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.formStatus==vpcrfConst.BTN_ADD}"
                                action="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.insert()}"
                                update="smsNotifyTemplateList,editPanel,@form" />
                            <p:commandButton rendered="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.formStatus==vpcrfConst.BTN_ADD}"
                                             value="#{lang['common.button.reset']}"
                                             immediate="true">
                                <p:ajax update="smsID,messTemplate,langId,templateCode,comments" resetValues="true" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                            <p:commandButton
                                value="OK"
                                rendered="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.formStatus==vpcrfConst.BTN_EDIT}"
                                action="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.update()}"
                                update="smsNotifyTemplateList,editPanel,@form" />
                            <p:commandButton rendered="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.formStatus==vpcrfConst.BTN_EDIT}"
                                             value="#{lang['common.button.reset']}"
                                             immediate="true"
                                             action="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.clearInput()}"
                                             update="smsID,messTemplate,langId,templateCode,comments"
                                             resetValues="true"/>     
                            <p:commandButton
                                value="#{lang['common.button.cancel']}"
                                action="#{smsNotifyTemplateController.reset()}"
                                immediate="true"
                                update="@form"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:fieldset>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation explains the difference. `deleteInBatch()` does the following:

> Deletes the given entities in a batch which means it will create a single Query. Assume that we will clear the EntityManager after the call.

whereas `delete()` does the following:

> Deletes the given entities.

So, the fist one will execute a delete JPQL query like

```
delete from SomeEntity e where e.id in :ids
```

whereas the second one will loop through the entities and call

```
entityManager.remove(entity)
```

Both should work, whether your entity has a foreign key or not. The second one will apply cascades whereas the first one won't. It's impossible to tell why you're having this issue without knowing anything about your code.

Comment: Hello. I updated the code in question. Can you help to clarify the issue. Thanks