# JpaRepository vs CRUDRepository findAll

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple question: why [JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--) is returning List of entities but [CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#findAll--) returns Iterable of entities?

Is it done on purpose? I guess it's because CrudRepository is more generic interface and there may be some specific repository which returns Iterable.

It makes harder to use CrudRepository without using specific JpaRepository..

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why it is harder can you give an example ?

Comment: Say, I want to get size of the returned items, in case of CrudRepository I'll have to count manually while(hasnext) counter++, on the list I can simply call size(). There are other similar things.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The class `CrudRepository` is part of the [Spring Data Commons project](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/1.9.3.RELEASE/reference/html/) and [is the recommended interface to extend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20784007/1126526) regardless of the actual data store used.

The reason `CrudRepository` methods return `Iterable` and not `List` (or `Set`) is because [some data stores allow streaming of results](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-21) and using a `Collection` type would result in loss of functionality for such stores.

Comment: Yes, that seems like an answer I was expecting. Can you give any example of such store please? After that I will accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: Check the last link in my answer where the Spring Data team has clarified the issue and given examples of data stores that provide streaming support.

Comment: To address concerns you have mentioned in your question, you can always have `interface BaseRepository<T, ID> extends CrudRepository<T, ID> { @Override List<T> findAll(); }`.  This is also what `JpaRepository` does.  This way, you can stick to the generic `CrudRepository` and still get the same functionality you are looking for (`Collection.size()`, etc.).

Comment: The last comment is awesome, will try to do that, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`JpaRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository`

and `PagingAndSortingRepository extends CrudRepository`.

This allows `JpaRepository` to have a more specific return type of `Itrable` which is `List`

Comment: Thanks, but it's not an answer :) I know that it CAN, I wonder WHY =)