# What exactly is the difference between JpaRepository and CrudRepository using Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a **Spring Boot** application that uses **Spring Data JPA** (on Hibernate 4) to access to my DB.

My doubt is related on the **DAO** interfaces (used by JPA to automatically generate the queries).

So, in my project I have these 2 interfaces:

1) **AccomodationDAO**:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface AccomodationDAO extends JpaRepository<Accomodation, Long> {

    Accomodation findById(@Param("id") Long id);

}
```

2) **EventDAO**:

```
public interface EventDAO extends CrudRepository<Event, Integer> {

    public Event findByLocation(Point location);

    public Event findById(@Param("id") Integer id);

}
```

They both works fine and use the same logic to declare queryes.

My only doubt is: the first one extends **JpaRepository** while the second one implements **CrudRepository**.

What exactly is the difference between **JpaRepository** and **CrudRepository**? What is the best choise to use or in what case is better use one instead the other choice?

Another doubt is: why my defined DAO interfaces extends **JpaRepository** and **CrudRepository** that are themselves interfaces? From what I know the interfaces are implemented and not extended...what am I missing?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring  In short, it's the same, but extend `CrudRepository` unless you need JPA-specific features.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that JpaRepository extends CrudRepository. Compare the JavaDoc of these two interfaces:

**[JpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)** vs **[CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true)**

In short `JpaRepository`

- has additional JPA specific methods that support for example [Query
  By Example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) , deleting in batches, manual flushing changes to database
- querying methods return `List`'s instead of  `Iterable`'s

<del>**If you are using JPA you should use JpaRepository.**</del>

Comment: Especially the last part is wrong. By all means try to avoid the store specific interfaces as using them leaks the persistence technology into the client. Store specific interfaces should only be used if the tweaked functionality in them is really needed. See my other answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20784007/18122

Comment: Lesson learned - thak you Oliver