# PaginationAndSortingRepository returning empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a application where I need to display some screens with `pagination`. I started with PaginationAndSortingRepository of Spring Data JPA .All seemed to work fine but when I executed the code I could not get the Data ,it returned empty without any error on eclipse console .

**Below is my code for controller :-**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/monatsultimodata" , method=RequestMethod.Get)
public List<Monatsultimo> getData(Pageable pageable){
List<Monatsultimo> dataList = null ;
try{
dataList= monatsultimoservice.getData(pageable)
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
return dataList;
}
```

**Below is my service code :-**

```
public List<Monatsultimo> getData(Pageable pageable){
List<Monatsultimo> tableData = new AarrayList();
monatsultimorepo.findAll(pageable)
return tableData;
}
```

**Below is my repository code :-**

```
@Repository
public interface MonatsultimoRepo extends 
PagingAndSortingRepository<MonatSultimo, Integer>{
}
```

**Below is my application.yaml file**

```
    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate:
                format_sql: true
                show_sql: true
                type: 'debug'
                use_sql_comments: true
                ddl-auto:update
server:
        port: 9000

security:
    basic:
        enabled: false
```

URL I am using to hit the Rest Service - localhhost:9000/Add to dictionary?page=0&size=25

everything goes right ,,till the time it return with no data .Please help me with this ,I have been struggling with it since days .

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: look your service code..

Comment: before ask such type of question on stack-overflow..review your code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before return `tableData` assign result of `monatsultimorepo.findAll(pageable)`to `tableData`

**Service:**

```
 public List<Monatsultimo> getData(){
   List<Monatsultimo> tableData = new AarrayList();
   tableData =monatsultimorepo.findAll()
   return tableData;
 }
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/monatsultimodata" , method=RequestMethod.Get)
   public List<Monatsultimo> getData(){
     List<Monatsultimo> dataList = null ;
     try{
       dataList= monatsultimoservice.getData()
     }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return dataList;
 }
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface MonatsultimoRepo extends JpaRepository<MonatSultimo,Integer>{
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate ,, lack of attention it is ,,feels so bad to spend time on this .But now it gives error cannot convert from Page<Monatsultimo> to List<Monatsultimo>

Comment: cannot convert from Page<Monatsultimo> to List<Monatsultimo>

Comment: because return type of  `monatsultimorepo.findAll(pageable)` is `Page<Monatsultimo>`

Comment: Why should not use `JpaRepository`....just change your `repository` code ..instead of `PagingAndSortingRepository` extends  `JpaRepository`..not change to any other thing

Comment: what are the benefits of using JpaRepository instead of PagingAndSortingRepository ????

Comment: read this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring

Comment: Changed it to JpaRepository still the same sir ,,, getting error in service , cannot convert from Page<monatsultimo> to List<MOnatsultimo>

Comment: why you passing `Pageable` reference to `getData` method in both controller and service

Answer (score 1):

Hi to provide paging within your spring application I would apply the following changes:

### Controller

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@RequestMapping(value="/monatsultimodata", method=RequestMethod.Get)
public List<Monatsultimo> getData(final @RequestParam("page") int page, 
       final @RequestParam("size") int size)
{
       List<Monatsultimo> dataList = null;

       try
       {
           dataList = monatsultimoservice.getData(new PageRequest(page, size));
       } catch(Exception e)
       {
           // Recommended output to a logger.
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return dataList;
}
```

### Service

The returned page object contains information such as total pages count - [page reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html).

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;

public List<Monatsultimo> getData(final Pageable pageable)
{
    Page<Monatsultimo> page = monatsultimorepo.findAll(pageable);
    return page.getContent();
}
```

Everything else will remain the same.