# The method findAll(Sort) in the type JpaRepository<Telefonbuch,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Telefonbuch>)

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, specifications

I want to implement `Specifications` and want to use the `findAll(Specification<T> spec)` method, but always when I insert an Specification Eclipse tells me:

```
The method findAll(Sort) in the type JpaRepository<Telefonbuch,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Telefonbuch>)
```

I don't want to use `Sort`. I hand over a specification so why does it always try to use the method with sort?

You can see here that the method is a suggestion by Eclipse:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfUFt.jpg

Specification:

```
public interface Specification<T> {
    Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder);
}
```

TelefonbuchSpecifications:

```
public static Specification<Telefonbuch> hasVorname(String vorname) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        return cb.equal(root.get(Telefonbuch_.vorname), "%"+vorname.toLowerCase()+"%");
    };
}
```

TelefonbuchRepository:

```
public interface TelefonbuchRepository extends JpaRepository<Telefonbuch, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Telefonbuch> {
```

SearchController:

```
public void search(String vorname, String nachname, String telefonnummer, String handynummer) {  
    if (!vorname.isEmpty()) {   
        List<Telefonbuch> list = telefonbuchRepository.findAll(TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(vorname));
    }
```

And here at the

```
List<Telefonbuch> list = telefonbuchRepository.findAll(TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(vorname));
        }
```

it tells me: 
`The method findAll(Sort) in the type JpaRepository<Telefonbuch,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Telefonbuch>)`

Answer (score 0):

`findAll` does exactly what it says: it finds *all* possibilities. So what you are trying to do is not making sense (filtering by first name).

`findAll` basically translates to `SELECT * FROM TABLE`

You will need to declare something in your repository which executes the query you are looking for, which I assume is `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE <CONDITION>`

As an example quoted from [the spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) portrays the following as a guideline:

The repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> { 
    List<Person> findByLastname(String lastname);
}
```

Application:

```
public class SomeClient {

  @Autowired
  private PersonRepository repository;

  public void doSomething() {
    List<Person> persons = repository.findByLastname("Matthews");
  }
}
```

You will need to define a query which adheres to your needed condition, instead of attempting to force a condition on the `findAll` shortcut.

Comment: You are definitely not right. findAll(Specification) gives me all entries for the given Specification but somehow it doesn't work. You can't tell me it's wrong what I'm doing if Spring itself gives a tutorial for that: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/
Yes it's possible to create your own findByMethod, but this one gave me an IllegalArgumentException: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077381/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-parameter-value-did-not-match-expected-type

Answer (score 0):

Your repository additionally needs to implement `JpaSpecificationExecutor` to see the `findAll(Specification<T>)` method.

Also, note that we don't recommend to extend `JpaRepository` in the first place but rather use one of the less revealing interfaces `CrudRepository` or `PagingAndSortingRepository`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring/20784007#20784007) for reference.

Comment: There's no need to be offensive. The declaration is outside the visible area. If you have it you need to check your IDE setup. I've seen Eclipse propose methods of types that have been added to a type in a different file but then complains about the method not being available as the other file has not been save. Might be worth checking. Other than that: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: How should I find or know what to setup else in Eclipse? I didn't changed anything. Just installed it.