# Spring InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element did not match expected type

Tags: spring, specifications

I already answered this question but got no feedback. So I'll try to ask the question different.
I want to use Specifications for my search requests. But it seems like the specification is not accessible or something, because it tells me:

```
javax.el.ELException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [com.auth0.samples.bootfaces.TelefonbuchSpecifications$1@20079547] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)];
```

This: `[com.auth0.samples.bootfaces.TelefonbuchSpecifications$1@20079547]`
with an @... does not seem to be right.

I just tried to follow this official Spring Tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/ or the one from DZone is the same https://dzone.com/articles/using-spring-data-jpa-specification

My classes:

```
public interface TelefonbuchRepository extends JpaRepository<Telefonbuch, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Telefonbuch> {

    public List<Telefonbuch> findByVornameOrNachname(String vorname, String nachname);
    public List<Telefonbuch> findByVorname(Specification<Telefonbuch> spec);
}
```

TelefonbuchSpecifications:

```
public class TelefonbuchSpecifications implements Specification<Telefonbuch> { //implements was a try

    public static Specification<Telefonbuch> hasVorname(String vorname) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            //return cb.equal(root.get(Telefonbuch_.vorname), "%"+vorname.toLowerCase()+"%");
            Predicate equalPredicate = cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Telefonbuch_.vorname)), "%"+vorname.toLowerCase()+"%");
            return equalPredicate;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Telefonbuch> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Method in SearchController:

```
 public void search(String vorname, String nachname, String telefonnummer, String handynummer) {  
List<Telefonbuch> list = telefonbuchRepository.findByVorname(TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(vorname));
```

vorname is a String defined in my Telefonbuch Model. If you need more classes or information please tell me. I'm very frustrated. Here also a picture of the project:
[image]

Comment: Remove the `findByVorname` that takes a `Specification`. That won't work. If you want to use the `Specification` use the `findAll` that takes a `Specification` from the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` instead.

Comment: Hey @M.Deinum i would wish you were right, but you aren't. Or maybe half right. I already opened a question here, but nobody has known the answer. When I do what you say my Eclipse always tells me: The method findAll(Sort) in the type JpaRepository<Telefonbuch,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Telefonbuch>)

I get the method with parameter Specification even as suggestion and also the sort one and he always picks the sort one. I don't get it. So it's like I give him something wrong and then he goes crazy.

Comment: The error you post here is about your `findByVorname` method. Those methods are validated at startup time and hence it fails. So you have to remove it.

Comment: I know. I deleted this like you said and used .findAll instead. And then i get the IDE error already. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110272/the-method-findallsort-in-the-type-jparepositorytelefonbuch-long-is-not-appl/54116901?noredirect=1#comment95115793_54116901

Comment: The fact that your IDE error doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Comment: And what should be the solution then? I can't start the application with this error. Already reinstalled Eclipse in different version and tested stuff.

Comment: @M.Deinum okay you are right I can start it, but when I press the button my browser tells me: Unresolved compilation problem: The method findAll(Sort) in the type JpaRepository<Telefonbuch,Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Specification<Telefonbuch>)

Comment: You need to change your second repository method to the following. public List<Telefonbuch> findByVorname(String vorname);

Comment: @joemokenela but then I wouldn't search with specifications. I know that Spring makes its possible to search like this. I did it the line above, when i began with the project. Then i tried predicates and then somebody told me to use specifications.

Comment: Why do you have your OWN `Specification` interface? You should use the one from Spring Data... Remove your own `Specification` interface and make sure you use the proper one.

Comment: @M.Deinum i'm sorry. Now my structure: I just moved the public static Specification from the TelefonbuchSpecifications to the TelefonbuchRepository and deleted the TelefonbuchSpecifications class. In my search controller i try to access it now with telefonbuchRepository.findAll(TelefonbuchRepository.hasVorname(vorname)); but again my IDE tells me that Sort is not applicable..

Comment: Again why do you have your own `Specification` interface? Delete that interface... IN your package there is an interface with the same name as the spring Data one. You are probably using the local one instead of importing the spring data one.

Comment: Oh gosh I love you. I had this one because the tutorials told me this... but they seem to be to old or I just understand them wrong. No more IDE failure. I can run the method even if I get not what i wanted. Thank you very very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @M.Deinum

the solution was a bit bigger.

[image]

Delete the Classes `Specification` & `TelefonbuchSpecifications`.

And just insert the `TelefonbuchSpecifications` as helper class in `TelefonbuchRepository`

```
public interface TelefonbuchRepository extends JpaRepository<Telefonbuch, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Telefonbuch> {

    public class TelefonbuchSpecifications {

        public static Specification<Telefonbuch> hasVorname(String vorname) {
            return (root, query, cb) -> {
                return cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Telefonbuch_.vorname)), "%" + vorname.toLowerCase() + "%");
            };
        }

        public static Specification<Telefonbuch> hasNachname(String nachname) {
            return (root, query, cb) -> {
                return cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Telefonbuch_.nachname)), "%" + nachname.toLowerCase() + "%");
            };
        }

    }
}
```

For the method `search` in `SucheController` then:

```
List<Telefonbuch> list = telefonbuchRepository.findAll(TelefonbuchSpecifications.hasVorname(vorname));
```