# CRUD repository does not respect UNIQUE constraint

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, h2

I have the following JPA entity

```
@Entity
class UserEntity {

    companion object {
        fun fromParameters(uuid: String, email: String, password: String, firstName: String, lastName: String) =
            UserEntity().apply {
                this.uuid = uuid
                this.email = email
                this.password = password
                this.firstName = firstName
                this.lastName = lastName
            }
    }

    @Id
    lateinit var uuid: String

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    lateinit var email: String

    @Column(nullable = false)
    lateinit var password: String

    @Column(nullable = false)
    lateinit var firstName: String

    @Column(nullable = false)
    lateinit var lastName: String
}
```

And this is my test to check the UNIQUE constraint, inserting another user with the same email.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
class TestUserCrudRepository {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userCrudRepository: UserCrudRepository

    private val testUserEntity = UserEntity.fromParameters(
        UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        "test@test.com",
        "password".toHash(),
        "Caetano",
        "Veloso"
    )

    @Test
    fun `when email already exists it should throw error`() {
        with (userCrudRepository) {
            save(testUserEntity)
            val newUserEntity = with (testUserEntity) { UserEntity.fromParameters(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), email, password, firstName, lastName) }
            shouldThrow<SQLException> { save(newUserEntity) }
        }
    }
}
```

The new entity always gets inserted with a duplicate email without any exception being thrown.

```
Expected exception java.sql.SQLException but no exception was thrown
```

I can see in the log that the table is created correctly with the given constraint.

```
Hibernate: drop table user_entity if exists
Hibernate: create table user_entity (uuid varchar(255) not null, email varchar(255) not null, first_name varchar(255) not null, last_name varchar(255) not null, password varchar(255) not null, primary key (uuid))
Hibernate: alter table user_entity add constraint UK_4xad1enskw4j1t2866f7sodrx unique (email)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because no `insert` statement issued.

Hibernate does not `flush` session *unless it has a good reason to do so*.

1. [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) is [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html?is-external=true). This means that the transaction a `@Test` method executed within is rolled back after the method returns.
2. `UserEntity` mapping also encourages hibernate to delay the `insert` (try using  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)` on `id` property to force issuing `insert`s)

Not diving into too much details the following happens when you run test:

1. Spring's test infrastructure `begin`s transaction
2. `@Test` method runs
3. `save(testUserEntity)` - Hibernate realizes that there is no reason to hit the database and *delays* the `insert`
4. `shouldThrow<SQLException> { save(newUserEntity) }` - same as previous
5. `@Test` method returns
6. Transaction rolls back. Hibernate does execute `insert`s because there is no reason to.

## How to fix it?

The most simple way to do it is to use [`JpaRepository#flush`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#flush--):

```
with (userCrudRepository) {
    save(testUserEntity)
    val newUserEntity = with (testUserEntity) { UserEntity.fromParameters(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), email, password, firstName, lastName) }
    save(newUserEntity)
    assertThrows<DataIntegrityViolationException> {
        flush()
    }
}
```

*Note that there is no `flush` method in [`CrudRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)*

*I guess that you have extended `CrudRepository`... You may want to extend `JpaRepository` instead.*

See: [What is difference between CrudRepository and JpaRepository interfaces in Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring)

---

**Note on exception**

You are expecting an [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/SQLException.html) to be thrown.

But note that [`DataIntegrityViolationException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html) will be thrown instead.

See: [Consistent Exception Hierarchy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#dao-exceptions)

Comment: Excellent answer, I just started on Spring Boot 3 days ago :) Annotating the test with `@Commit` does not solve my problem because I'm checking the exception before the test method ends. I extended `JpaRepository` as you suggest and caught the exception on `flush()` and used `@Rollback` on the test to avoid it throwing an `UnexpectedRollbackException`. Maybe you want to update your answer with these.

Comment: Oh, I just missed some moments. `@Commit` will throw exception *outside* of `@Test` (I removed this part of the answer). You do not need to use `@Rollback`. Wrapping `flush` into [`assertThrows`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.junit.jupiter.api.function.Executable)) should be enough. I was able to get `UnexpectedRollbackException` only if `@Commit` is present on `@Test`. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you:)