# CrudRepository Vs JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am learning Spring boot. In the DAO interface, i see some documents use CrudRepository, some use JpaRepository, some others use a Custom Generic interface.

In which  case should i use CrudRepository, JpaRepository or the custom one.

here is an example of the interface

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, Long> {  }
```

Comment: `JpaRepository` is a `CrudRepository` but with some additional JPA specific methods on it. If you don't need those JPA specific methods, then use `CrudRepository` else use `JpaRepository`.

Comment: Does [What is difference between CrudRepository and JpaRepository interfaces in Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring) help you?