# Repository implementing just the JpaSpecificationExecutor causes error while starting Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, repository, crud-repository

we were facing issues while starting our Spring Boot Application. We added a new API with a Controller, a Service class, and two Repository classes for two tables. This is the master table repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;    
import com.sixdee.wallet.core.domain.PromoTicketMaster;

@Repository
public interface PromoTicketMasterRepo extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<PromoTicketMaster> {

}
```

We had a look at this answer [What is difference between CrudRepository and JpaRepository interfaces in Spring Data JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14025100/7218656) before creating this Repo as it was used for Pagination methods as well. It said that **Because of the inheritance mentioned above, JpaRepository will have all the functions of CrudRepository and PagingAndSortingRepository** . But the application didn't start with this Repo configuration and the console showed this error. The autowiring was fine.

```
*************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field promoTicketMasterRepo in com.sixdee.wallet.core.service.impl.PromoTicketServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.sixdee.wallet.core.repository.PromoTicketMasterRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sixdee.wallet.core.repository.PromoTicketMasterRepo' in your configuration.
```

Then we changed the Repo like this and the application was started.

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sixdee.wallet.core.domain.PromoTicketMaster;

@Repository
public interface PromoTicketMasterRepo extends JpaSpecificationExecutor<PromoTicketMaster>, CrudRepository<PromoTicketMaster, String> {

}
```

What was wrong with the first approach

Comment: Specifications are not a Repository interface. See https://reflectoring.io/spring-data-specifications/

Comment: Then @Chris, what is the use of extending the above-mentioned interfaces.

Comment: Check out the methods within it and decide for yourself the value; JpaSpecificationExecutor adds search functionality, while CrudRepository and JpaRepository add save/search type methods. Why Spring didn't have one extend the other is a question for Spring, not StackOverFlow, but likely done as away to allow adding the behaviour to any repos - to pick and choose which to apply this to independently.