# Spring Boot: How to add a condition to findAll repository method

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Probably the question is not correct so I will try to explain the problem well. I'm developing a mini project with spring boot for the creation of a calendar in which any registered user can add events to his calendar.So at the moment I have a page in which I can see the list of all the inserted events, So at the moment I have a page in which I view the list of all the inserted events, but the events are retrieved via the `findAll()` method so each user sees all the events registered in the database. Obviously my goal is to recover from the db only the events of the specific logged in user.When I create an event the foreign key is the user's id so I just need to figure out how to build the query in spring.

This is my User.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();

}
```

This is my Event.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "event_title", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Titolo evento obbligatorio")
    private String eventTitle;

    @Column(name = "event_description", nullable = false)
    private String eventDescription;

    @Column(name = "event_date", nullable = false)
    @NotBlank(message = "Data evento obbligatoria")
    private String eventDate;

    @Column(name = "start_time", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private int startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private int endTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
}
```

EventRepository:

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {

}
```

Method in the controller to display the event list:

```
 @GetMapping("/day")
    public String calendar(@AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails userDetails, Model model) {
        String email = userDetails.getUsername();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(email);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("events", eventRepository.findAll());
        return "day";
    }
```

I'm quite newbie with spring so I couldn't even find anything on the internet, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, you should be able to extend your `EventRepository` like so:

```java
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
  public Iterable<Event> findByUser(User user);
}
```

You'll then be able to call the `findByUser` method from your service by passing the user you want to query for.

I'd recommend taking a look at Spring JPA and its `JpaRepository`. It extends the functionality of `CrudRepository` with more options such as paging. It also returns `List<>` instead of `Iterable<>`, which if often useful. You can find [further comparisons elsewhere on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring) too.

Comment: thanks a lot I solved the problem, thanks also for the advice on the JpaRepository I think I will use it for event pagination